# The easiest (and most consistent) way to access a LAN device

Tags: networking, ip, lan, webserver

I want to create a website which only LAN users will be able to see. I plan to use my Raspberry Pi as a server, since the website will be a small one (only HTML-CSS-JS). 
The only method I know to access the page is entering the local IP address of the target device. But this address is changing from time to time. Is there a consistent way to connect to that device?

Comment: one thing you could do is give it a static ip, this  can be  done from the device itself ..or it might be possible from the router based on the device's MAC Address.   An alternative is there is a service called dyndns that can give a domin where the computer with changing IP will update the service with the current IP .  I don't know if there is a local version, there is a dyndns forum.

Answer (score 1):

You should read this article, it will be of help to you.

**https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/how-to-make-a-machine-accessible-from-the-lan-using-its-hostname**

I would personaly configure your router that it will reserve this device IP in its DHCP configuration so that it would not change.